# Can C# extension methods access private variables?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is it possible to access an object's private variables using an extension method?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No. You can do the same in an extension method as in a "normal" static method in some utility class.

So this extension method

```
public static void SomeMethod(this string s)
{
    // do something with 's'
}
```

is equivalent to some static helper method like this (at least regarding what you can access):

```
public static void SomeStringMethod(string s)
{
    // do something with 's'
}
```

(Of course you could use some reflection in either method to access private members. But I guess that's not the point of this question.)

Comment: +1. As an aside, you can have private extension methods; there's a nice article on this at http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/05/private-extension-methods.aspx Extension methods can also access private static members of their static utility class.

Comment: Even though this is tagged as C#, this applies to any of the .NET languages which provide support for extension methods.

Comment: @TrueWill - but since they must be static, non-nested, non-generic types, they can't really have private access to any *object's* variables. `internal` access, sure - but not `private`.

Answer (score 27):

No it cannot.

However, you will be interested to know that the other answers are incorrect in saying that normal static methods cannot access private fields. **A static method can access private non-static member fields in its own class.** The following code is perfectly valid and shows a static method accessing a private field:

```
public class Foo
{
    private bool _field;

    public static bool GetField(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo._field;
    }
}
```

Now... back to your question. You might think that an extension method should be able to do the same thing, given the (non-existent) "equivalence" to static methods that other answers claim exists. However, you cannot declare extension methods inside a nested class. So if you try to do the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    private bool _field;

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool GetField(this Foo foo)
        {
            return foo._field;
        }
    }
}
```

You will get a compile error saying

> Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; Extensions is a nested class

Note that, interestingly enough, removing the `this` keyword causes the code to compile fine. The reasons for this are discussed here:

1. [Why are extension methods only allowed in non-nested, non-generic static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class)
2. [Why not allow Extension method definition in nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443842/why-not-allow-extension-method-definition-in-nested-class/12037840#12037840)

Answer (score 11):

No:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string bar;
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void Test(this Foo foo)
    {
        // Compile error here: Foo.bar is inaccessible due to its protection level  
        var bar = foo.bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

## Use Reflection

Not recommended, but you could possibly access any private variable of any type using another extension method like so:

```
public static T GetFieldValue<T>(this object obj, string name) {
    var field = obj.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return (T)field?.GetValue(obj);
}
```

And then access a private field of an arbitrary type:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
string privateBar = foo.GetFieldValue<string>("_bar");
```

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, unless you give some kind of access to them through public properties or a proxy pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the class that you are extending, you can always declare the class partial, then extend the class and have access to all the private members in a different file...  But you wouldn't really be using extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method is essentially a static method so all you have access to are the public members of the instance on which the extension method is invoked on