# Extended list not working when written inline with rest of code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, extension-methods

I am trying to implement grenade's response from thsi thread on how to randomize a list: [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp). The solution includes creating an extended list. Here is the exact way it's written in my own code:

```
    static class MyExtensions
{
    static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I try to run the method in a button click event on a list I created when said event is triggered, VS does not recognize the method and produces this error:

System.Collections.Generic.IList does not contain a definition for 'Shuffle' and no extension method 'Shuffle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList could be found..."

Here is my attempted usage for reference:

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    IList<int> dayList = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        dayList.Add(i);
    }

    dayList.Shuffle();

    More code...

    }
```

I've searched these boards and found that I need to declare the namespace in which the extension method is, but mine is inline with the rest of my page, so there is no namespace to declare. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for this in your MyExtensions file:

```
namespace MyApp.Namespace
{
```

Now add this at the very top of your form:

```
using MyApp.Namespace;
```

`MyApp.Namespace` is only a placeholder for your namespace, of course.
If your extensions are in different project you would have to add a reference to this project.
You may also want to make your `MyExtensions` public.

Comment: The MyExtensions extension is inline with the rest of my page, nested in the same <script runat="server"> tag as the buttonclick event in which I try to call it.

Comment: Then change it.. Apparently there is no way to do it your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class

Comment: That's a helpful article. Okay, with that in mind, I'll just create a separate namespace in my current project and call it like any other namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you are importing MyExtensions in the form class where you are using it.

Comment: this could have been confirmed in the comments

Comment: That sounds like a possible oversight. I'm brand new to C# so I honestly didn't know I had to do that. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: just use using MyExtensions at start of the namespace of your form