# Reason for the extension method to be defined in static class?

Tags: .net

I cant figure out why Microsoft has made it compulsory to define the extension methods in static class. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are extension methods only allowed in non-nested, non-generic static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class)

Comment: It says extension methods were designed to make LINQ work and LINQ only needs extension methods in static, non-generic, non-nested classes to work. But I could not get the reason why LINQ needs static extension classes only?