# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'CustomMethod' and no accessible extension method 'CustomMethod'

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I put the code in a separate extending method, but ide doesn't see it. I'm getting next error `'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSwagger' and no accessible extension method 'AddSwagger' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` What could be the reason?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwagger();
        builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

        ...
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (\"Bearer {token}\")",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });

            options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
        });
    }
}
```

If I move the method to another class, then everything works fine. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are extension methods only allowed in non-nested, non-generic static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an extension method, the class containing it also has to be marked as `static`.

From your example it appears that the `AddSwagger` method is within `Program` class which isn't marked `static`. You would need to move the `AddSwagger` method to another class that is marked static.

```
public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
      // your logic here 
    }
}
```

For more information look at this - [How to implement and call a custom extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method)