# .NET Add Class Method to System Class

Tags: .net, class, datetime, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t C# static class extension methods supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909156/why-arent-c-sharp-static-class-extension-methods-supported)

**General question:**

In Objective-C, I can add a category to any (I think?) class. In that category, I can define class or instance methods.

I know how to make an extension method in .NET that will allow me to implement the same thing as Objective-C category instance methods.

Is there a way to make an extension method that is a class method?

**Specific question:**

I have created a method that takes a `System.DateTime` value and returns another `System.DateTime` value that represents the first of the month that precedes the supplied value. I have turned this into an extension method, and I call it as follows:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = Now.FirstOfPriorMonth()
```

However, I only ever call this method on `Now`, so I'd like to make a class-level extension method and assume `Now`. Thus, I would like to call the following:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = System.DateTime.FirstOfLastMonth()
```

Is this possible? I realize that my currently-working solution is fine, so I'm really more wondering what's possible than trying to "fix" my current problem.

Comment: Share your experimental classes to check...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't get all caught up trying to extend Microsoft's static class: just start your own common date/time utilities class and use that:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = YourCommonCode.DateTimeUtils.FirstOfLastMonth()
```