# C#, an extension method to return a string list of named constants from any enum

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I'm trying to make an extension method that can apply to all/any enum, that returns the string constants of the enum as a list of strings.

this did not work.

```
static class EnumEx
{
    public static List<string> ToList(this System.Enum e)
    {
        return System.Enum.GetNames (e.GetType()).ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm calling it like:

```
public enum TestEnum { HELLO, WORLD };

foreach(string e in TestEnum.ToList())
    Console.Writeline(e);
```

UPDATE:

```
TestEnum instance = new TestEnum();
foreach(string e in instance.ToList())
        Console.Writeline(e);
```

and get the errors:

Type `string[]' does not contain a member`ToList' and the best extension method overload `EnumEx.ToList(this System.Enum)' has some invalid arguments
Extension method instance type`string[]' cannot be converted to `System.Enum'

Comment: what didn't work ? be more specific

Answer (score 3):

When using extension methods, you need an instance on which to call that method.  Using your method, you can do this:

```
var instance = new System.ConsoleModifiers();
Console.WriteLine(instance.ToList().Count());
```

If you want more information about why C# doesn't support static extension methods, you can read about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914207/573218

Comment: Hehe, I didn't even know you could 'new' up an `Enum`. It's too bad you can't add custom methods to an `Enum` derived type. That's the only feature Java has that I wish C# had.

Comment: Oh I see, extension methods can only be called on instances. But I'm still receiving errors listed above.