# Extension Methods with Custom Classes

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm attempting to extend my custom classes and running into a problem where it cannot find the extension method..  I have and can extend any built in classes or even ones contained within DLL's.  I don't know if this is a compilation error or if I'm doing something wrong.  Threw together a small program for an example, won't compile..

Here's the extension:

```
namespace ExtensionMethodTesting.Extension
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static void DoSomething(this ExtensionMethodTesting.Blah.CustomClass r)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Custom Class:

```
namespace ExtensionMethodTesting.Blah
{
    public class CustomClass
    {
        public static void DoNothing()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code calling it:

```
using ExtensionMethodTesting.Blah;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExtensionMethodTesting.Extension;

namespace ExtensionMethodTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomClass.DoNothing();
            CustomClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something...  Anyways the exact error just for clarification is:

> Error  1   'ExtensionMethodTesting.Blah.CustomClass' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomething'   c:\users\damon\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ExtensionMethodTesting\ExtensionMethodTesting\Program.cs   16  25  ExtensionMethodTesting

Comment: just curious... why are you writing extension methods on classes that you control? Is there a reason you can't just add the methods where they belong? (I ask because you generally *don't* want to do what you're doing...)

Comment: Mostly due to multiple developer issues.  Most of it will be accomplished with inheritance instead, but there are some one off things that I'll need to extend.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield What is your bases for saying: *"you generally don't want to do what you're doing..."*

Comment: there are some limits and edge cases with extension methods (especially related to overloads) that are not always intuitive. They exist for the purpose of extending classes in ways you _can't_ otherwise do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension methods require an instance of an object. You'll have to `new` up a `CustomClass` to use it.

```
var custom = new CustomClass();
custom.DoSomething();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914207/182821) as to why that is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate an object of the `CustomClass` to use its extension method.

```
CustomClass obj = new CustomClass();
obj.DoSomething();
```